Should I put black garbage bags on the inside or outside of my windows to keep my house warm and cold from getting in?
I live in an older house and I can feel the cold air coming in through the windows. Should I put black trash bags on the outside or inside to keep my house warmer?

stopping the air flow is far more important than trapping more heat; cram toilet paper into the cracks with a credit card to cheaply seal it up.

Are you talking about covering the whole window with a stretched-out bag, or covering the joint between the wall and the window with a rolled bag? I assumed the latter when I read your question, but the accepted answer appears to assume the former.

@dandavis Agreed. Though caulking and/or injected foam would be best.

Consider a layer of clear plastic bubble wrap instead of opaque black plastic.  Its already  double-layered

I assume you're thinking of using black so that it will absorb sunlight and add to the heat in the room.   Clear would do a better job for two reasons.   First, almost all of the sunlight coming in will get absorbed bouncing around in your room and heat those objects anyway.  Second, having the heat generated on the layer that is losing heat to the outside will cut that benefit in 1/2.

TL;DR Inside
For a bunch of reasons, inside is better than outside, including:

Damage - Inside, the plastic will basically last forever, or at least through the winter. Outside you have birds, wind, rain and other natural, uncontrollable, things that can mess up the plastic.
Aesthetics - Admittedly, black garbage bags inside won't look fantastic from the outside. But almost any plastic over the windows on the outside will look awful. In a worst-case scenario, someone may think black plastic covering the windows is due to broken windows, and broken windows (even if they turn out not to be broken in this case) encourage vandalism and other crime.
Ease of Installation One - This varies from house to house, but at a minimum second-story window coverings are as easy to install as first-story window coverings when done from the inside. But from the outside that means ladders, possibly over dirt or bushes or other things besides flat pavement.
Ease of Installation Two - To be effective, you need a good seal at the edges. Whether that is by using shrinkable plastic or duct tape, it is fairly easy to do inside but outside there are often different materials such as brick around the sides of windows that make it harder to seal the plastic.

That being said, consider a couple of alternatives:

If you must use bags (i.e., cheapest readily available material), use white bags instead. That will hopefully let at least a little bit of light through. They aren't generally as large as the black bags, but it should be possible to tape them together (for the larger windows) and make it work.
If you can spend just a little bit more, consider getting a window insulation kit like this one from Amazon:


The details vary. Some have thicker plastic than others. They have different types of tape for the edges. But the premise is generally:

Clear plastic to cover the windows, so you can still get natural light
Something to hold the plastic at the edges
Use a hair dryer (a heat gun might be better, but the average homeowner has a hair dryer and these are designed for easy DIY installation with no special tools) to "heat shrink" to hold the plastic really tight

The idea of "dead air between plastic and windows" is exactly the same with taping up plastic bags. But these kits do a much better (and more attractive) job of it.

I'd recommend against a heat gun, simply because it can create a lot hotter air than a hair dryer, likely causing the plastic window film to melt.

40-odd years ago this worked well in upstate NY winters. But it wasn't fancy plastic requiring a hair dryer... Always mounted on the outside, not inside.

@Milwrdfan Agreed. I think the consumer kits are specifically designed for hair dryer temperature because most consumers don't have a heat gun.

If the windows are single-pane, the foil will significantly improve insulation. They are nigh invisible on white frames, too. (Own experience.) +1 for the suggestion.

If using bags instead of plastic sheets, both white and clear plastic bags are available at sizes and prices comparable to black plastic bags. Clear plastic sheets that are available for other purposes (e.g., a drop cloth for painting) are also available and might be even less expensive, depending on source.

Nearly 40 years ago I recall helping my grandparents fit their reusable sheets of acrylic (maybe 1-3 mm) - and take them down in spring.  These also stopped the draught from the join in their sash windows.  That was on the inside (partly @JonCuster)

At a similar time to @ChrisH my parents were putting heavy duty clear plastic sheeting over the outside of their single pane windows each winter.  (Similar in appearance to a plastic shower curtain, but I don't know if it was anything special or not.)  They've since replaced all but one really large one; it's had a sheet of 1/4" (6mm) plexiglass semi-permanently installed for the last 30ish years.


Should I put black trash bags on the outside or inside to keep my house warmer?

No.
Your question reflects a common misconception about radiant heat. Black surfaces do indeed build heat from sunlight, but so do most of the other surfaces in your home. Also, even if you were to use black plastic on the inside, much of the heat generated would be lost to leakage back out the window. Then, the poor environment* that blackened windows creates is not worth the minor improvement in radiant heating you might gain.
Let the light reach more of your room for more benefit and greater comfort. Use clear plastic on your windows to block air leaks (by far a more significant benefit) and provide some level of insulation value while still allowing light transmission. Window kits exist for a reason and aren't terribly expensive. They allow you to tighten the film so it's nearly transparent.

* Mental and physical health depends on adequate exposure to light. The light and views that windows provide are more important than you might think.

I had the same objection. Most light (and with it its energy) is trapped inside the room anyway. Tackle the problems through better window insulation, as in manasseh's answer.

I'd like to underscore the footnote... the studies are all in:   light makes everything better

Not.
From second hand experience I can tell you that if you get an unexpected moment of strong sunshine on them, they can melt stuck to your window. Use something like cloth instead. That I'd put on the inside to prevent it getting wet.

I would tend to go with isherwood's answer. Clear plastic would be the superior choice, mounted on the inside.
Whereas black surfaces do indeed collect heat readily, they also are superior radiators of heat and the laws of thermodynamics show that the rapidity of heat transfer from hot to cold is dependent on the difference in temperature between a hot area and a cold area (the difference is called the 'delta-t').
In your case, the black plastic is at the window (arguably colder than the room it adjoins), so a black covering would tend to radiate heat beck out in that direction, toward the window, simply due to the color of the plastic.
In essence, it would have a tendency to absorb heat from your room and radiate it back out the window, probably not what you had in mind.
Clear plastic, on the other hand, would let the sun in and act as an improved barrier to heat transfer, not the most efficient, but better than no second barrier at all.
Go to Home Depot or your favorite big-box home improvement store in your part of the country and get a roll of painters dropcloth, the thin lightweight stuff.
Mount it with blue painter's masking tape so it doesn't pull the paint off your walls when you take the plastic down. That would be your best bet.

In the end, the heat will get out, but window glass is not transparent to IR radiation in the room temperature band, so it's a bit more complicated than just radiating it out.

Yes, 'the heat will get out'. All we can do is slow it down. As for UV, the transmittance in window glass for low, medium and high bands vary with material inclusions and thickness, but show 100% transmittance in the 350-1400 nm range.

See: Fig 2-2, link

Infrared at room temperature is at 8 to 25 µm. Just try with an infrared thermometer, point it at the open sky with the windows closed, it will show the temperature of the glass, open the window it will show something like -40 or under range.

I would lean towards putting them on the inside. There are usually gaps between the window frame and the rough opening in the wall to facilitate installing a square and plumb window in a not-square-and-plumb rough opening. Air can get through these gaps. In more modern homes these gaps are insulated and filled, but it is possible they may not be in your home.
If you attach the plastic to the wall around the window, it will cover the whole window and the gaps that may be leaking air behind the window frame and trim.
Note that connecting the plastic to the wall may involve tape, which opens the question of how to keep the wall finish intact when removing the tape when the weather gets warmer. This could be the subject of a new question.
Also, putting the plastic inside keeps the outside of the house looking like it usually does.
Note that black garbage bags will not be easy to see through. Sunlight is good for mental health. Maybe clear plastic may be better, with thick curtains when light needs blocking out.
